# Argument dump format error on starting a rails server

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

When I try starting a rails server, I keep getting this error before the server starts up:

```
ArgumentError: dump format error(Â¸)
              load at org/jruby/RubyMarshal.java:148
              load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046
```

My jruby version is *jruby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385)*

I'm using *rails 3.1.4* and *java version 1.7.0_65*

I've been struggling with this for a few days and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update JRuby to it's latest 1.7.x (**1.7.16.1** or at least 1.7.13) ... there's been a lot of Ruby (1.9.3) compatibility (e.g. encoding related) fixes since 1.7.3, it's not worth exploring the issue on it.

if it still happens, you should try if it's the same failure on MRI. it also would be valuable (esp. for yourself) to upgrade to latest Rails in 3.1.x if you can not go to a supported 3.2.x release.

in any case, please note that the question is very likely not answerable without knowing further details about your application/environment.